# Error in deployment of shinyapps Error accessing GitHub repository nstrayer/shinysense. HTTP 401: Unauthorized

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to publish a shiny app, you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/Sustainscapes/MobileApp/blob/main/ComplexApp.R), it was being deployed correctly until I tried using the shinysense package

This is the error I get:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1134600463 failed: Error building image: Error fetching shinysense (0.2.0) source. Error accessing GitHub repository nstrayer/shinysense. HTTP 401: Unauthorized
Execution halted
```

The full log is as follows:

```
----- Deployment log started at  2022-04-13 03:57:51  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/Documents/MobileApp", appFileManifest = "/tmp/a99d-ac93-a2ac-32b6",      appPrimaryDoc = "ComplexApp.R", account = "derek-corcoran",      server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "MobileApp", appId = 6012536,      launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE,          ignoredFiles = ".RData|app2.R|app3.R|app4.R|AppSolo.R|Geo.R|MobileApp/app.R|MobileApp/rsconnect/shinyapps.io/derek-corcoran/MobileApp.dcf|Photo.R|R/SpeciesCount.R|R/SpeciesSelect.R|SimpleApp.R|Untitled 1.odt|www/pwa-service-worker.js"),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3   rsconnect_0.8.25
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /v1/applications/6012536 946ms
----- Bundle upload started at  2022-04-13 03:57:52  -----
[2022-04-13 03:57:52] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2022-04-13 03:57:52] Bundling app dir 
[2022-04-13 03:57:52] Generate manifest.json 
[2022-04-13 03:57:52] Starting to perform packrat snapshot 

Adding these packages to packrat:
                      _           
    MASS                7.3-54    
    Matrix              1.4-0     
    R6                  2.5.1     
    RColorBrewer        1.1-2     
    RJSONIO             1.3-1.6   
    Rcpp                1.0.8.3   
    askpass             1.1       
    attempt             0.3.1     
    base64enc           0.1-3     
    bit                 4.0.4     
    bit64               4.0.5     
    bslib               0.3.1     
    cachem              1.0.6     
    cli                 3.2.0     
    clipr               0.8.0     
    colorspace          2.0-3     
    commonmark          1.8.0     
    cpp11               0.4.2     
    crayon              1.5.1     
    crosstalk           1.2.0     
    curl                4.3.2     
    d3r                 1.0.0     
    digest              0.6.29    
    dplyr               1.0.8     
    ellipsis            0.3.2     
    fansi               1.0.3     
    farver              2.1.0     
    fastmap             1.1.0     
    fontawesome         0.2.2     
    fs                  1.5.2     
    generics            0.1.2     
    geoloc              0.0.0.9500
    ggplot2             3.3.5     
    glue                1.6.2     
    gridExtra           2.3       
    gtable              0.3.0     
    here                1.0.1     
    hms                 1.1.1     
    htmltools           0.5.2     
    htmlwidgets         1.5.4     
    httpuv              1.6.5     
    httr                1.4.2     
    isoband             0.2.5     
    jquerylib           0.1.4     
    jsonlite            1.8.0     
    labeling            0.4.2     
    later               1.3.0     
    lattice             0.20-44   
    lazyeval            0.2.2     
    leaflet             2.1.0     
    leaflet.providers   1.9.0     
    lifecycle           1.0.1     
    magrittr            2.0.3     
    markdown            1.1       
    mgcv                1.8-35    
    mime                0.12      
    munsell             0.5.0     
    nlme                3.1-152   
    openssl             2.0.0     
    pillar              1.7.0     
    pkgconfig           2.0.3     
    png                 0.1-7     
    prettyunits         1.1.1     
    progress            1.2.2     
    promises            1.2.0.1   
    purrr               0.3.4     
    r2d3                0.2.3     
    rappdirs            0.3.3     
    raster              3.5-15    
    readr               2.1.2     
    rlang               1.0.2     
    rprojroot           2.0.3     
    rstudioapi          0.13      
    sass                0.4.1     
    scales              1.1.1     
    shiny               1.7.1     
    shiny.pwa           0.2.1     
    shinyMobile         0.9.1     
    shinyStore          0.1.0     
    shinyWidgets        0.6.4     
    shinysense          0.2.0     
    sourcetools         0.1.7     
    sp                  1.4-6     
    stringi             1.7.6     
    stringr             1.4.0     
    sys                 3.4       
    terra               1.5-21    
    tibble              3.1.6     
    tidyr               1.2.0     
    tidyselect          1.1.2     
    triebeard           0.3.0     
    tzdb                0.3.0     
    urltools            1.7.3     
    utf8                1.2.2     
    vctrs               0.4.0     
    viridis             0.6.2     
    viridisLite         0.4.0     
    vroom               1.5.7     
    withr               2.5.0     
    xfun                0.30      
    xtable              1.8-4     
    yaml                2.3.5     

[2022-04-13 03:57:55] Completed performing packrat snapshot 
[2022-04-13 03:57:55] Writing Rmd index if necessary 
[2022-04-13 03:57:55] Compressing the bundle 
POST /v1/bundles 604ms
[2022-04-13 03:57:56] Starting upload now 
PUT /bundles/application-6012536/7a1ad49724cc4fffbcedb2ccd944c8df.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTK7PZPDNFD&Signature=nZhE4pzwdA0NkeOX225RIuqo29U%3D&content-md5=uPwSYrDEA7xVKGsnIUP6mg%3D%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar&x-amz-security-token=FwoGZXIvYXdzELv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDElUzAfn10D%2Bsxoj%2BSKtAX9Vth%2FbmVo45kOCt4BU1ZAYkfK3vTQzPEMTvWOjt2iJMOxEUOuNwJKhNknsqNeh%2BA6%2BqnFk1PrgJ3tP%2BVOHF1C%2FzaC9JP0CPYdkez%2FUpAshuUgDYmitWUAockFviNldehklG6x23pt%2FpcK2x3XuosKcQyfHAjLd3eeyhxpaW3v%2FDiZVlnT9yOI3aZqXdzPEXKblIAbL3MOnWT5A7lCQF%2FOeJSYqPmHIFBItQRDhKPfY2JIGMi1Zs4%2FI2hNRo0vHp7vRa%2FT6FdUk%2Fsd1uyK36413bkHrWCpBd9GaLr2NoAvSITc%3D&Expires=1649818676 1011ms
[2022-04-13 03:57:57] Upload complete 
POST /v1/bundles/5792416/status 517ms
GET /v1/bundles/5792416 501ms
[2022-04-13 03:57:58] Saving deployment record for MobileApp -  
----- Server deployment started at  2022-04-13 03:57:58  -----
POST /v1/applications/6012536/deploy 864ms
Waiting for task: 1134600461
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 503ms
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 600ms
  building: Building image: 6759879
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 661ms
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 597ms
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 838ms
  building: Fetching packages
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 589ms
  building: Building package: shinysense
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461 528ms
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
GET /v1/tasks/1134600461/logs/ 599ms
GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:34030&filter=parent_id:1134600461&count=100&offset=0 564ms
GET /v1/tasks/1134600463/logs/ 586ms
GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:34030&filter=parent_id:1134600463&count=100&offset=0 496ms
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
----- Deployment error -----
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1134600463 failed: Error building image: Error fetching shinysense (0.2.0) source. Error accessing GitHub repository nstrayer/shinysense. HTTP 401: Unauthorized
 
----- Error stack trace -----
4: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/Documents/MobileApp", appFileManifest = "/tmp/a99d-ac93-a2ac-32b6", 
       appPrimaryDoc = "ComplexApp.R", account = "derek-corcoran", 
       server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "MobileApp", appId = 6012536, 
    ...
3: client$waitForTask(taskId, quiet)
2: stop(status$error, call. = FALSE)
1: (function (e) 
   {
       cat("----- Deployment error -----\n")
    ...
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1134600463 failed: Error building image: Error fetching shinysense (0.2.0) source. Error accessing GitHub repository nstrayer/shinysense. HTTP 401: Unauthorized
Execution halted
```

Comment: I am having similar issues? Were you able to resolve it?